# Программное создание ToggleButton в Android. Не работает позиционирвоание

Tags: android

Есть код:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));

    .........

    final ToggleButton myLightButton = new ToggleButton(this);
    myLightButton.setText("BTN1");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    myLightButton.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    addContentView(myLightButton, lp2);
```

Сама кнопка отображается, но в верхнем левом углу, а в нижнем правом не хочет

Пробовал так:

```
        ToggleButton myLightButton = new ToggleButton(this);
    myLightButton.setText("LightButton");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParam1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonParam1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    buttonParam1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    myLightButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParam1);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(param);

    relativeLayout.addView(myLightButton);
    addContentView(myLightButton, param);
    //setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Но тогда кнопка не отображается, или создается новый layou с кнопкой как надо, но полностью закрывает графику, которая у меня выводится в MyView()

Comment: а почему бы не через хмл?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в `addContentView` передавать другой объект `LayoutParams`.

Comment: Не очень понял. Т.е. создать еще один объект LayoutParams?

Comment: Именно так!